# AHFormatterV7の自動分析とanalyzer.batを使って、組版結果のレイアウトに対する注釈付きのPDFを書き出ししたい。

Tags: xsl-fo, 組版

https://github.com/AntennaHouse/analysis-utility
analyzer.batの[65～73行目](https://github.com/AntennaHouse/analysis-utility/blob/6392380002e9c23b7d88b1a5cbc2f7f9f6f0e5af/analyzer.bat#L65)を次のように編集しましたが、コマンド入力についての内容？が表示されるだけで処理されません。

どのように入力すれば解決するか、もしご存知でしたら、お教えいただけますでしょうか。
（情報があまりに少なく、なかなか解決方法が見当たらないので。）

何卒宜しくお願いします。

---

入力内容

```
rem Command-line parameter defaults
set lang=ja
set ahfcmd="C:\Program Files\Antenna House\AHFormatterV70\AHFCmd.exe"
set d="K:～04.xml"
set opt=-x 4
set xslt="manual.xsl"
set xsltparam= 
set transformer=msxsl
set format=annotate
set force=all
```

コマンドプロンプトによる実行結果

[image: 実行結果]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

手元に環境が無いので試せていませんが、analyzer.bat のデフォルト値の部分を直接編集するのではなく、bat ファイルを実行する際の引数として渡すことが想定されているように読めます。

```
analyzer -d 処理して欲しいファイル -lang ja -ahfcmd "C:\Program Files\Antenna House\AHFormatterV70\AHFCmd.exe" -opt "-x 4" -xslt "manual.xsl" -transformer msxsl
```

Comment: アドバイスいただいた内容で、テストし動作しました。
ありがとうございます、助かりました。